# How to remove unknown file extensions from files using script

Tags: shell, csh, tcsh

I can remove file extensions if I know the extensions, for example to remove .txt from files:

```
foreach file (`find . -type f`)
    mv $file `basename $file .txt`
end
```

However if I don't know what kind of file extension to begin with, how would I do this?

I tried:

```
foreach file (`find . -type f`)
mv $file `basename $file .*`
end
```

but it wouldn't work.

Comment: Are there additional "."s in the file names? If not, I would try   
    ```foreach file (find . -type f)  
    set newfile = `basename file | awk 'BEGIN{FS="."}{print $1}'`  
    mv $file $newfile  
    end```

Comment: Which shell are you using?  Csh?  You might get better responses if you tagged it with the correct tag ([tag:csh]), assuming I've identified it correctly.  I've edited the tag for you — fix if I'm wrong.

Comment: @IanChang: Do you *have* to do it in csh? Csh is [not very convenient](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html) for programming.

Comment: @IanChang: Please consider for next time: if you want an answer that works on a specific `shell`, please specify the `shell` when you post the question. Originally, you only posted this question with the `shell` tag and I and other folks spent our time writing `bash` answers that will not work on the `csh` shell, which you specified later.

Answer (score 3):

What shell is this? At least in bash you can do:

```bash
find . -type f | while read -r; do
    mv -- "$REPLY" "${REPLY%.*}"
done
```

(The usual caveats apply: This doesn't handle files whose name contains newlines.)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker True, but I never claimed it did, and when I wrote this answer, the question didn't mention any particular shell.

Comment: Alright, fair enough :-) Didn't check the entire question history, but in general csh questions have a habit of accumulating bash answers ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use sed to compute base file name.

```
foreach file (`find . -type f`)
    mv $file `echo $file | sed -e 's/^\(.*\)\.[^.]\+$/\1/'`
end
```

Comment: Why not just `s/\.[^.]\+$//`?

Comment: I agree, to cut the extension is even better.

Answer (score 2):

**Be cautious:** The command you seek to run could cause loss of data!

If you don't think your file names contain newlines or double quotes, then you could use:

```
find . -type f -name '?*.*' |
sed 's/\(.*\)\.[^.]*$/mv "&" "\1"/' |
sh
```

This generates your list of files (making sure that the names contain at least one character plus a `.`), runs each file name through the `sed` script to convert it into an `mv` command by effectively removing the material from the last `.` onwards, and then running the stream of commands through a shell.

Clearly, you test this first by omitting the `| sh` part.  Consider running it with `| sh -x` to get a trace of what the shell's doing.  Consider making sure you capture the output of the shell, standard output and standard error, into a log file so you've got a record of the damage that occurred.

Do make sure you've got a backup of the original set of files *before* you start playing with this.  It need only be a `tar` file stored in a different part of the directory hierarchy, and you can remove it as soon as you're happy with the results.

You can choose any shell; this doesn't rely on any shell constructs except pipes and single quotes and double quotes (pretty much common to all shells), and the `sed` script is version neutral too.

Note that if you have files `xyz.c` and `xyz.h` before you run this, you'll only have a file `xyz` afterwards (and what it contains depends on the order in which the files are processed, which needn't be alphabetic order).

If you think your file names might contain double quotes (but not single quotes), you can play with the changing the quotes in the `sed` script.  If you might have to deal with both, you need a more complex `sed` script.  If you need to deal with newlines in file names, then it is time to (a) tell your user(s) to stop being silly and (b) fix the names so they don't contain newlines.  Then you can use the script above.  If that isn't feasible, you have to work a *lot* harder to get the job done accurately — you probably need to make sure you've got a `find` that supports `-print0`, a `sed` that supports `-z` and an `xargs` that supports `-0` (installing the most recent GNU versions if you don't already have the right support in place).

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple:

```
$ set filename=/home/foo/bar.dat
$ echo ${filename:r}
/home/foo/bar
```

See more in [man tcsh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh), in "History substitution":

> r
>
> Remove a filename extension '.xxx', leaving the root name.